# Putting a sequence into a matrix around existing values

Tags: r, matrix, seq

I want to generate a symmetric matrix around a diagonal of zeroes and a predetermined sequence around them. In theory the lines should show as

```
0 1 3 5 7 9
1 0 3 5 7 9
```

I've tried tweaking with the conditionals, but I suspect that it's wonky because of indexing, which I am nowhere near skilled enough to fix.

```
bend <- function(n){
  m <- seq(1, n, by=2)
  a <- length(m)
  y <- matrix(nrow= a, ncol = a, byrow= TRUE)
  y <- ifelse(row(y) == col(y), 0, m)
  y
}
```

Assuming that the input is a 9, expected output is

```
0 1 3 5 7 9    
1 0 3 5 7 9 
1 3 0 5 7 9    
1 3 5 0 7 9    
1 3 5 7 0 9    
1 3 5 7 9 0
```

Actual output is

```
0 3 5 7 9 1    
3 0 7 9 1 3    
5 7 0 1 3 5    
7 9 1 0 5 7    
9 1 3 5 0 9    
1 3 5 7 9 0
```

Comment: That is not a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simpler way to do what you need. You can start off by creating a `matrix` of `length(x) + 1` columns and rows with all elements as a logical `TRUE`. Then make the diagonal `FALSE` using `diag()`. Now you can replace the `TRUE`s with your desired vector. The diagonal being `FALSE` is not affected. Since the values are replaced column-wise you need a final transpose `t()` to get correct result.

This way, you don't need to worry about tracking indices.

```
x <- c(1,3,5,7,9)

make_matrix <- function(x) {
  m <- matrix(TRUE, ncol = length(x) + 1, nrow = length(x) + 1)
  diag(m) <- FALSE
  m[m] <- x
  t(m)
}

make_matrix(x)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    1    0    3    5    7    9
[3,]    1    3    0    5    7    9
[4,]    1    3    5    0    7    9
[5,]    1    3    5    7    0    9
[6,]    1    3    5    7    9    0
```

Here's another way with `sapply`. This creates the necessary row elements in each iteration and puts them in a matrix by column. Again, you need a `t()` to get correct results. -

```
sapply(0:length(x), function(a) append(x, 0, after = a)) %>% t()

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    1    0    3    5    7    9
[3,]    1    3    0    5    7    9
[4,]    1    3    5    0    7    9
[5,]    1    3    5    7    0    9
[6,]    1    3    5    7    9    0
```

**Benchmarks -**

`sapply` is slower, likely because it's creating the matrix elements one row at a time and calls `append` for every row. All this overhead is avoided in the `make_matrix()` approach.

```
x <- sample(100)

microbenchmark(
  make_matrix = make_matrix(x),
  sapply = t(sapply(0:length(x), function(a) append(x, 0, after = a))),
  akrun_forloop = {
    n <- length(x) + 1
    m1  <- matrix(0, n, n)
    for(i in seq_len(nrow(m1))) m1[i, -i] <- x
  },
  times = 1000
)

Unit: microseconds
          expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
   make_matrix  111.495  117.5610  128.3135  126.890  135.7540   225.323  1000
        sapply  520.620  551.1765  592.2642  573.335  602.2585 10477.221  1000
 akrun_forloop 3380.292 3526.3080 3837.1570 3648.765 3812.5075 20943.245  1000
```

Comment: Might want to add a couple of comments. Code-only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: @42- I thought the code was simple enough. Anyway's added some explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I came up with a solution but when I compared it to your second one, it was substantially identical. Your first one seemed a bit obscure, since not everyone will be familiar with R matrix indexing operations, so I suspect others will appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Feel free to add your solution here or separately; I'll add it to the benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple `for` loop

```
n <- length(x) + 1
m1  <- matrix(0, n, n)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(m1))) m1[i, -i] <- x
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    0    1    3    5    7    9
#[2,]    1    0    3    5    7    9
#[3,]    1    3    0    5    7    9
#[4,]    1    3    5    0    7    9
#[5,]    1    3    5    7    0    9
#[6,]    1    3    5    7    9    0
```

#### data

```
x <- c(1,3,5,7,9)
```